Unable to send packet using IPPROTO_RAW socket in C++ (MacOS 14.7 Sonoma)
As a learning exercise to further my understanding of the networking stack & OSI model, I'm attempting to implement an HTTPS client from scratch in C++ from layer 3 and above. I can't seem to get SOCK_RAW / IPPROTO_RAW sockets working - the program exits successfully and says it has sent data over the socket, but when I inspect with WireShark I don't see any packets sent. On the other hand, when I implement the same program using the layer 4 socket() abstractions, I'm able to view the sent packets in WireShark successfully.
My objective is to successfully send an IPv4 packet using the SOCK_RAW / IPPROTO_RAW socket implementation in C++, and validate that the packet has been sent (and is of the expected structure) using WireShark.
Here is my layer 3 program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bit>

#define DEBUG true;
#define FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH 20

template <typename type>
void print(type message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

std::string convert_char_array_to_hex(uint8_t* data, int length) {
    std::stringstream ss;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        ss << std::hex << (int) data[i] << " ";
    }

    return ss.str();
}

struct ipv4_packet {

    ipv4_packet() {
        
    }

    ~ipv4_packet() {
        delete[] contents;
        delete[] options;
    }
    
    void set_version(uint8_t version) {
        this->version = version;
        octets[0] = octets[0] | (version << 4);
    }

    void set_ihl(uint8_t header_length) {
        this->ihl = header_length;
        octets[0] = octets[0] | (header_length << 0);
    }

    void set_dscp(uint8_t dscp) {
        this->dscp = dscp;
        octets[1] = octets[1] | (dscp << 2);
    }
    
    void set_ecn(uint8_t ecn) {
        this->ecn = ecn;
        octets[1] = octets[1] | (ecn << 0);
    }

    void set_length(uint16_t length) {
        this->length = length;
        uint16_t length_n = htons(length);
        octets[2] = octets[2] | ((length_n >> 0) & 0xff);
        octets[3] = octets[3] | ((length_n >> 8) & 0xff);
    }

    void set_identification(uint16_t identification) {
        this->identification = identification;
        uint16_t identification_n = htons(identification);
        octets[4] = octets[4] | ((identification_n >> 0) & 0xff);
        octets[5] = octets[5] | ((identification_n >> 8) & 0xff);
    }

    void set_flags(uint8_t flags) {
        this->flags = flags;
        octets[6] = octets[6] | (flags << 5);
    }

    void set_fragement_offset(uint16_t fragment_offset) {
        this->fragment_offset = fragment_offset;
        uint16_t fragment_offset_n = htons(fragment_offset);
        octets[6] = octets[6] | ((fragment_offset_n >> 0) & 0xff);
        octets[7] = octets[7] | ((fragment_offset_n >> 8) & 0xff);
    }

    void set_time_to_live(uint8_t ttl) {
        this->time_to_live = ttl;
        octets[8] = ttl;
    }

    void set_protocol(uint8_t protocol) {
        this->protocol = protocol;
        octets[9] = protocol;
    }

    void set_header_checksum(uint16_t checksum) {
        this->header_checksum = checksum;
        uint16_t checksum_n = htons(checksum);
        octets[10] = octets[10] | ((checksum_n >> 0) & 0xff);
        octets[11] = octets[11] | ((checksum_n >> 8) & 0xff);
    }

    void set_source_address(uint32_t address) {
        this->source_address = address;
        uint32_t address_n = htonl(address);
        octets[12] = octets[12] | ((address_n >> 0) & 0xff);
        octets[13] = octets[13] | ((address_n >> 8) & 0xff);
        octets[14] = octets[14] | ((address_n >> 16) & 0xff);
        octets[15] = octets[15] | ((address_n >> 24) & 0xff);
    }

    void set_destination_address(uint32_t address) {
        this->destination_address = address;
        uint32_t address_n = htonl(address);
        octets[16] = octets[16] | ((address_n >> 0) & 0xff);
        octets[17] = octets[17] | ((address_n >> 8) & 0xff);
        octets[18] = octets[18] | ((address_n >> 16) & 0xff);
        octets[19] = octets[19] | ((address_n >> 24) & 0xff);
    }

    // num_options_specified is the number of 32 bit data structures specified in the options,
    // even if there are more than one options specified per 4-octet (32 bits). 
    void set_options(uint32_t *options, size_t num_options_specified) {
        this->options = new uint32_t[num_options_specified];
        memcpy(this->options, options, num_options_specified * 4);
        this->num_options_specified = num_options_specified;
    }

    void set_contents(uint8_t *contents, size_t num_content_bytes) {
        this->contents = new uint8_t[num_content_bytes];
        memcpy(this->contents, contents, num_content_bytes);
        this->num_content_bytes = num_content_bytes;
    }

    void calculate_and_set_derived_values() {
        set_ihl(FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH / 4 + num_options_specified);
        set_length(FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH + num_options_specified * 4 + num_content_bytes);
        
        int checksum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += 2) {
            checksum += (((int) octets[i]) << 8) + octets[i+1];
        }

        // TODO: Add support for counting options in checksum

        checksum = htonl(checksum);
        checksum = ~ntohl(checksum + (checksum << 16)) & 0xffff;

        set_header_checksum((uint16_t) checksum);
    }

    void cast_to_byte_array(uint8_t* buffer) {
        uint8_t* fixed_packet_header_bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(this);
        uint8_t* optional_header_bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(options);

        memcpy(buffer, fixed_packet_header_bytes, FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH);
        memcpy(buffer + FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH, optional_header_bytes, ihl * 4 - FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH);
        memcpy(buffer + ihl * 4, contents, length - ihl * 4);
    }

    uint8_t octets[20] = { 0 };
    uint32_t* options;
    uint8_t* contents;
    
    uint8_t version = 0;
    uint8_t ihl = 0;
    uint8_t dscp = 0;
    uint8_t ecn = 0;
    uint16_t length = 0;
    uint16_t identification = 0;
    uint8_t flags = 0;
    uint32_t fragment_offset = 0;
    uint8_t time_to_live = 0;
    uint8_t protocol = 0;
    uint16_t header_checksum = 0;
    uint32_t source_address = 0;
    uint32_t destination_address = 0;
    
    size_t num_options_specified = 0;
    size_t num_content_bytes = 0;

} __attribute__((packed));

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // --- INSTANTIATE A SINGLE IPv4 PACKET --- //

    ipv4_packet packet;
    packet.set_version(4); // IPv4
    // Don't manually set the header length, let the ipv4_packet class calculate it
    packet.set_dscp(0);
    packet.set_ecn(0);
    // Don't manually set the total length, let the ipv4_packet class calculate it
    packet.set_identification(0);
    packet.set_flags(0b010); // No-Fragment
    packet.set_fragement_offset(0);
    packet.set_time_to_live(64);
    packet.set_protocol(6); // TCP
    // Don't manually set checksum, let the ipv4_packet class calculate it
    packet.set_source_address(0xc0a80143);
    packet.set_destination_address(0x12d57ba5);

    uint32_t options[] = { };
    uint8_t contents[] = { 0xef, 0xc5, 0x01, 0xbb, 0xa8, 0x69, 0x15, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x02, 0xff, 0xff, 0x70, 0xc9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0x05, 0xb4, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x06, 0x01, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0a, 0x92, 0xa9, 0x7a, 0x4a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 };

    packet.set_options(options, 0);
    packet.set_contents(contents, 44);
    packet.calculate_and_set_derived_values();

    uint8_t* packet_buffer = new uint8_t[packet.length];
    packet.cast_to_byte_array(packet_buffer);
    int packet_length = packet.length;
    print("PACKET AS HEX: ");
    print(convert_char_array_to_hex(packet_buffer, packet_length));
    print("PACKET LENGTH: ");
    print(packet_length);

    // --- OPEN A SOCKET, SEND THE ABOVE PACKET --- //

    int sockfd, res, IP_HDRINCL_ON = 1;

    sockaddr_in destination_address;
    destination_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("18.208.8.205");
    destination_address.sin_port = htons(443);
    
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    res = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &destination_address, sizeof(destination_address));
    if (res < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting to socket");

    res = send(sockfd, packet_buffer, packet_length, 0);
    if (res < 0)
        error("ERROR sending on socket");

    print("Number of bytes sent: ");
    print(res);

    delete[] packet_buffer;
}

That I compile and run with the following command:
 g++ ./server.cpp -std=c++20 && sudo ./a.out

And it results in the following output:
PACKET AS HEX: 
45 0 0 40 0 0 40 0 40 6 ea 52 c0 a8 1 43 12 d5 7b a5 ef c5 1 bb a8 69 15 83 0 0 0 0 b0 2 ff ff 70 c9 0 0 2 4 5 b4 1 3 3 6 1 1 8 a 92 a9 7a 4a 0 0 0 0 4 2 0 0 
PACKET LENGTH: 
64
Number of bytes sent: 
64

Unfortunately, I can't really show the "lack" of WireShark logs in a meaningful way for this one but please take my word that when I run the same query as I do for the below program, nothing is returned in WireShark.
Layer 4 program (WireShark logs at bottom):
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bit>

#define DEBUG true;
#define FIXED_IPV4_HEADER_BYTE_LENGTH 20

template <typename type>
void print(type message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sockaddr_in destination_address;
    destination_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("18.208.8.205");
    destination_address.sin_port = htons(443);

    int sockfd, res;

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    res = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &destination_address, sizeof(destination_address));

    if (res < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting to socket");

    print("Number of bytes sent: ");
    print(res);
}

Program Output:
Number of bytes sent: 
3

WireShark logs:


Please remove C tag from your question. There is no such things in C: std, ::, template, andtypename. Besides, there is no C/C++ program at all.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the current incarnation of your program. It looks like you are trying to send a single TCP packet with payload. But TCP does not work like this. You would need to establish the TCP connection first (handshake with SYN, ACK etc) before you can send packets with payload.

Which interface are you sending the packet out on? You haven’t specified one, and I’m not sure how Linux picks one “by default” for raw sockets. You might want to explicitly specify the interface, or check Wireshark on other interfaces to see if the packet is being sent on one of them.

Iman - removed. Thanks.
Steffen - in future iterations of this, I will be implementing the TCP handshake and further logic. I need to crawl before I can walk though and the first step is sending a single IP packet. Cheers!

Nneonneo - I'm using the "Wi-Fi: en0" interface. This interface worked for the layer 4 program above, so I expect it should also work with the layer 3 program.
